# FixedCredentialsProvider gives unauthorized exception when calling Google Cloud service

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to call Google Cloud DocumentAI through a google service account. I have the json key that was generated for it and I load it into my application via the `FixedCredentialsProvider` and a `GoogleCredentials` object since it's not possible to load it via environment variables for my use case. This method used to work but now it throws an `UNAUTHORIZED` exception and something related to not having valid OAuth2 tokens. When I test the scenario using the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable it works fine. Has there been a change that doesn't allow the `FixedCredentials` method anymore? I have not updated the sdk, it just stopped on its own. Is there a new way to load the credentials JSON key programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up inspecting the SDK source to find the answer. The difference between loading via environment variables and using the `GoogleCredentials` is that in the latter case it does **not** provide OAuth2 `scope`s which is something that since last testing has become mandatory from Google's side for DocumentAI service. Loading the key using the environment variables goes from a different code path that provides some **default** scopes. We can provide the same scopes manually when loading via `GoogleCredentials` like so:

```
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
    .fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonKeyFile))
    .createScoped(DocumentUnderstandingServiceSettings.getDefaultServiceScopes());
DocumentUnderstandingServiceClient client = DocumentUnderstandingServiceClient.create(
      DocumentUnderstandingServiceSettings.newBuilder()
      .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(googleCredentials))
      .build()
);
```

The `DocumentUnderstandingServiceSettings.getDefaultServiceScopes()` returns a static variable that contains the same scopes that are used by the environment variable loading method which in turn enables usage of DocumentAI with the manually created `GoogleCredentials`.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me from wasting a lot of time :D

Comment: I couldnt find DocumentUnderstandingServiceClient  maven repository